# MVC3 jQuery updating Model from TextBox Blur

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

Firstly, let me say that I am quite new to MVC3 so I may be doing something that isn't quite right. I've tried to search for an answer but I think I may be using the wrong search terms.

**Question:-**I have a form that allows a user to enter a From value and a To value. Once the From value has been entered I would like to update the StartTime value on the Model using jQuery. I would then continue down the form filling in To and Quantity before finally clicking OK and sending the values back to the Controller.

*How do I go about updating the StartTime on the model when the From text box loses focus?*

```
public class DetailsModel
{
    public string From{get;set;}
    public string To {get;set;}
    public int Quantity{get;set;}
    public DateTime StartTime{get;set;}
}
```

and in my view there is a bit of jQuery as follows

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#From').blur(function () {
            alert('Work out how to set StartTime On Model here');
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: How about you mark the answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, first of all, you can use javascript to get the current time, no need to go to the server. If you really want to go to the server, you can use Ajax and store the value in a hidden field.

```
$(function () {

    $('#From').blur(function () {

        $.get('getTime', function(data){               
            $('#someHiddenField').val(data);
        });

    });

});
```

Or you can get really nuts and create a session variable called startTime and set the time there. Then when you submit the form, grab the value from there.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer:  You can't.  Once the page is in the client, the model is gone.  It doesn't exist.

The only way to update the model is to post the values back to the server.

What you probably want to do instead is to change the values on the local client, using a hidden field to hold the updated values once you finally post them back to the server.  You then update the StartTime locally to reflect that.

You have a fundamental misunderstanding of the separation of the server and client.  The model only exists on the server, not on the client.  You want to make changes on the client, which is fine.. but you must track those changes locally and then submit them later.

The alternative is to continue to post updates to the server.. but that's very wasteful.

Comment: I realise that the Model only exists on the server maybe my question was badly worded. I think what I was trying to get at was is it possible for the Blur event to call the server to get the Time and return it as part of a new model without doing a Post of the whole form.

Comment: @lostinwpf - Well, this is primarily what ajax is for.  It allows you to post data to the server, receive an update, and modify the existing page without a full page refresh.

Answer (score 0):

```
    $('input[name=From]').change(function () {
        $('#StartTime').val(set_your_value_here);
    }
```

I have found input change to work more often than blur.

Comment: Gho5t's answer is better if the trip to the server is required...except I would have thought you need an Ajax .Post rather than .Get.